# Как запустить страницу после build

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

После `npm run build` пытаюсь открыть index.html в папке build, но в ней получаю ошибки:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В package.json прописано `"homepage": "./build"`.

Пробовал прописывать в pachage.json `"homepage": "./"`, тогда в консоль выводится огромное кол-во непонятных ошибок:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение создаю через `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После npm run build у вас создается билд в соответсвующей папке. Не нужно открывать html. Пропишите в папке проекта serve -s build -p 5000, после зайдите на http://localhost:5000(Порт можно поменять). Подробнее можете прочитать тут https://cra.link/deployment